# How to format axes and dates in jqPlot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have a page with 3 different charts. I'd like to make them look good. Here's what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY0Yl.jpg

As you can see there are several problems with the formatting here.

1. How do I make the Y-axis labels align? In this case, they're right aligned, and the graph starts at the right. So, since the labels are different, each of the graphs starts in a different column.
2. How do i remove the first and last or the X-axis labels? In this case, two things happen. In one side, the label overlaps the Y-label, and on the other side, the label wraps around and uses two lines.
3. How do I space the graphs? Each graph is its own DIV container, and it's jqPlot that decides to format it, and overrides my DIV formatting.

Answer (score 0):

For point 3 you may be able to place each div inside an additional div that you will be able to format with CSS as you want. And if it work you may reuse your hide X axis solution with a better result.